# 70-80’s scifi space machine aliens

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens, space, artificial-intelligence

Robot invaders that start off as rock/eggs and then use tentacles to build bodies out of parts and maybe humans parts too and the “egg is head” with green visor eye. I remember a dude and a girl using a machine gun in open space to get away from the ship explosion.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Is this a TV show or a movie?  Live-action or animated?  They were using the recoil from the gun as an improvised rocket?

Comment: It’s a movie, think B rated also. They were using the gun for thrust kinda like a rocket.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This reminds me of [Moontrap](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0097911/), a 1988 movie about space robots, there are tentacles and parts (human and otherwise) seen and mentioned in the [trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=270j3YK2YMU). Not sure about green visor eye (trailer shows red one), but rest does match.

Comment: You are amazing! That’s the movie! And yep, looks like I was wrong on the eye color, been almost 25 years since I last seen it. Thanks!